# Netplan ipv6 "No route to host"

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ipv6, netplan

I've clearly misconfigured my ipv6 listener addresses.  Question 1: I need someone to spot the error. And a bonus Question 2: is there any risk to removing the "/sbin/ip address add" command below?

This is on a ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine.

Here's a curl command, showing that ipv6 routing is not set up correctly:

```
curl -vvv -L "http://[2600:1303:d000:1::17c3:4571]"
*   Trying 2600:1303:d000:1::17c3:4571...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2600:1303:d000:1::17c3:4571: No route to host
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

Previously, when the program started, it issued a native "/sbin/ip address add".  That turned out to be problematic because when the network interface was reset, the route would be lost.

So, I added /etc/netplan because configuring the ipv6 routing survives a network restart.  However, I didn't remove the "ip addr add" on startup.  Currently, two commands are used to setup routing: netplan and "/sbin/ip address add".  Here's the order of commands executed:

```
1.  Manual one-time command of "/etc/netplan apply" which didn't return any errors.  

2.  "ip addr add" every time the server starts.  So, at least once since the manual netplan command.
```

Here's the ipv6 addresses it's listening on:

```
netstat -anp | grep redir | grep LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 2600:1303:d000:1::17:80 :::*                    LISTEN      3187/my-service
tcp6       0      0 2600:1303:d000:1::17:80 :::*                    LISTEN      3187/my-service
tcp6       0      0 2600:1303:d000:1::17:80 :::*                    LISTEN      3187/my-service
tcp6       0      0 2600:1303:d000:1::17:80 :::*                    LISTEN      3187/my-service
tcp6       0      0 2600:1303:d000:1::17:80 :::*                    LISTEN      3187/my-service
```

Here's what I want it to be listening on:
    [2600:1303:c000:1::15d4:456f]:80"
    [2600:1303:d000:1::17c3:4570]:80"
    [2600:1303:d000:1::17c3:4571]:80"
    [2600:1303:d000:1::17c3:4572]:80"

Here's the "ip address add" command.  Notice that the I'm using "/24" and I wonder if that's the problem.  Or perhaps using both "ip addr add" and netplan isn't working as intended.  This is a legacy application and because my networking skills in this area aren't strong, I wasn't sure if it would be safe to remove the "ip addr add".  I didn't think it would hurt to keep the "ip addr add" command, but perhaps I was wrong.

```
out, e = exec.Command("/sbin/ip", "-6", "addr", "add", ip + "/24", "dev", "eth0").CombinedOutput()
```

Here's my netplan config file.  Note that this is only part of the file; for security reasons I'm not including the mac address, name servers or gateway.  However, they are correct because my ipv4 addresses work.  Also, I haven't posted the real ipv6 addresses for security reasons as well.

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses: [ '2600:1303:d000:1::17c3:456e/24', '2600:1303:d000:1::17c3:4570/24', '2600:1303:d000:1::17c3:4572/24', '2600:1303:d000:1::17c3:4571/24', '2600:1303:d000:1::17c3:456f/24' ]
```

Thanks in Advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of problems:

1. There was no gateway6.
2. The bit mask should have been "/64" instead of "/24"

Netplan wouldn't delete the old routes.  I had to do following steps:

```
1.  ip -6 addr del 2600:1303:d000:1::17c3:456f/24 dev eth0
2.  netplan apply
```